Obstacle's margin in Navigation2 costmap
I am using ROS2 humble with setup for differential drive robot of rectangular shape. I need my robot to move close to obstacles (~5 cm from the walls). I am not able to achive that with Nav2 Smac Lattice planner since the obstacle (wall) margin is too large. I was trying to reduce inflation radius but below a certain value (around 0.28m) the inflation radius is not going to be showed, either increasing cost_scaling_factor doesn't help. Below there are two images with inflation_radius value of 0.3m and 0.05m (focusing now only on local costmap). Is it possible to reduce the margin (cyan color on the below images) while keeping inflation layer? Or it should be as it is without the inflation layer in case of cleaning robot's application?


My nav2 config:
amcl:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    alpha1: 0.2
    alpha2: 0.2
    alpha3: 0.2
    alpha4: 0.2
    alpha5: 0.2
    base_frame_id: "base_footprint"
    beam_skip_distance: 0.5
    beam_skip_error_threshold: 0.9
    beam_skip_threshold: 0.3
    do_beamskip: false
    global_frame_id: "map"
    lambda_short: 0.1
    laser_likelihood_max_dist: 2.0
    laser_max_range: 20.0
    laser_min_range: -1.0
    laser_model_type: "likelihood_field"
    max_beams: 60
    max_particles: 2000
    min_particles: 500
    odom_frame_id: "odom"
    pf_err: 0.05
    pf_z: 0.99
    recovery_alpha_fast: 0.0
    recovery_alpha_slow: 0.0
    resample_interval: 1
    robot_model_type: "nav2_amcl::DifferentialMotionModel"
    save_pose_rate: 0.5
    sigma_hit: 0.2
    tf_broadcast: true
    transform_tolerance: 1.0
    update_min_a: 0.2
    update_min_d: 0.25
    z_hit: 0.5
    z_max: 0.05
    z_rand: 0.5
    z_short: 0.05
    scan_topic: /lidar/scan
    set_initial_pose: false # Published from script
    always_reset_initial_pose: false
    first_map_only: false
    initial_pose:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      yaw: 0.0

amcl_map_client:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

amcl_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    odom_topic: /odom
    navigators: ["navigate_complete_coverage", "navigate_through_poses", "navigate_to_pose"]
    #default_nav_through_poses_bt_xml: $(find-pkg-share nav2_bt_navigator)/behavior_trees/navigate_through_poses_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
    default_nav_through_poses_bt_xml: $(find-pkg-share navigation)/behavior_trees/navigate_through_poses_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
    default_nav_to_pose_bt_xml: $(find-pkg-share navigation)/behavior_trees/navigate_w_recovery_and_replanning_only_if_path_becomes_invalid.xml
    #default_nav_to_pose_bt_xml: $(find-pkg-share navigation)/behavior_trees/navigate_w_recovery_and_replanning_path_if_not_in_goal_proximity.xml
    #default_coverage_bt_xml: $(find-pkg-share opennav_coverage_bt)/behavior_trees/navigate_w_basic_complete_coverage_nav_to_start.xml
    default_coverage_bt_xml: $(find-pkg-share opennav_coverage_bt)/behavior_trees/navigate_w_basic_complete_coverage_nav_to_start_replanning.xml
    #default_coverage_bt_xml: $(find-pkg-share opennav_coverage_bt)/behavior_trees/navigate_w_basic_complete_coverage.xml
    navigate_through_poses:
      plugin: "backported_bt_navigator/NavigateThroughPosesNavigator"
    navigate_complete_coverage:
      plugin: "opennav_coverage_navigator/CoverageNavigator"
    navigate_to_pose:
      plugin: "backported_bt_navigator/NavigateToPoseNavigator"
    bt_loop_duration: 10
    default_server_timeout: 20
    plugin_lib_names:
      - opennav_compute_complete_coverage_action_bt_node
      - opennav_cancel_complete_coverage_action_bt_node
      - nav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node
      - nav2_compute_path_through_poses_action_bt_node
      - nav2_follow_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_back_up_action_bt_node
      - nav2_spin_action_bt_node
      - nav2_wait_action_bt_node
      - nav2_clear_costmap_service_bt_node
      - nav2_is_stuck_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_reached_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updated_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_initial_pose_received_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_reinitialize_global_localization_service_bt_node
      - nav2_rate_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_distance_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_speed_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_truncate_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updater_node_bt_node
      - nav2_recovery_node_bt_node
      - nav2_pipeline_sequence_bt_node
      - nav2_round_robin_node_bt_node
      - nav2_transform_available_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_time_expired_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_distance_traveled_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_single_trigger_bt_node
      - nav2_is_battery_low_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_navigate_through_poses_action_bt_node
      - nav2_navigate_to_pose_action_bt_node
      - nav2_remove_passed_goals_action_bt_node
      - nav2_planner_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_controller_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_checker_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_get_pose_from_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_path_longer_on_approach_bt_node
      - nav2_controller_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_globally_updated_goal_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_is_path_valid_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_is_goal_nearby_condition_bt_node
    error_code_names: 
      - compute_path_error_code 
      - follow_path_error_code
      - compute_coverage_error_code

bt_navigator_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

coverage_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    default_headland_width: 0.3
    robot_width: 0.525
    operation_width: 0.525
    min_turning_radius: 0.005
    linear_curv_change: 200.0
    coordinates_in_cartesian_frame: true
    default_allow_overlap: true
    default_swath_angle_type: "BRUTE_FORCE"
    default_swath_type: "NUMBER"
    default_step_angle: 0.261799 # radians (15 deg)

bt_navigator_navigate_complete_coverage_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True




controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    controller_frequency: 20.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.5
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    failure_tolerance: 0.3
    progress_checker_plugin: "progress_checker"
    goal_checker_plugins: ["general_goal_checker"] 
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]

    # Progress checker parameters
    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::PoseProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.25
      required_movement_angle: 0.5
      movement_time_allowance: 10.0
    
    general_goal_checker:
      stateful: True
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.1
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.05

    # RPP parameters
    FollowPath:
      plugin: "nav2_regulated_pure_pursuit_controller::RegulatedPurePursuitController"
      desired_linear_vel: 0.5
      lookahead_dist: 2.0
      min_lookahead_dist: 0.6
      max_lookahead_dist: 2.5
      lookahead_time: 5.0
      rotate_to_heading_angular_vel: 1.8
      use_velocity_scaled_lookahead_dist: true
      min_approach_linear_velocity: 0.05
      approach_velocity_scaling_dist: 0.6
      use_collision_detection: true
      max_allowed_time_to_collision_up_to_carrot: 0.5
      use_regulated_linear_velocity_scaling: true
      use_fixed_curvature_lookahead: false
      curvature_lookahead_dist: 0.25
      use_cost_regulated_linear_velocity_scaling: false
      regulated_linear_scaling_min_radius: 0.9
      regulated_linear_scaling_min_speed: 0.25
      use_rotate_to_heading: true  # allows to follow coverage path better in sharper turns
      allow_reversing: false
      rotate_to_heading_min_angle: 0.785
      max_angular_accel: 3.2
      #max_robot_pose_search_dist: 10.0
      use_interpolation: true

controller_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 5.0
      publish_frequency: 2.0
      global_frame: odom
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: False
      rolling_window: true
      width: 3
      height: 3
      resolution: 0.05
      #robot_radius: 0.42
      footprint: "[ [0.336, 0.273], [0.336, -0.273], [-0.336, -0.273], [-0.336, 0.273] ]"
      plugins: ["obstacle_layer", "voxel_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        inflation_radius: 0.55
        cost_scaling_factor: 1.5
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /lidar/scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
      voxel_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"
        enabled: True
        publish_voxel_map: True
        origin_z: 0.0
        z_resolution: 0.05
        z_voxels: 16
        max_obstacle_height: 2.0
        mark_threshold: 0
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /lidar/scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      static_layer:
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  local_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False
  local_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False

global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 1.0
      publish_frequency: 1.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: True
      #robot_radius: 0.42
      footprint: "[ [0.336, 0.273], [0.336, -0.273], [-0.336, -0.273], [-0.336, 0.273] ]"
      resolution: 0.05
      track_unknown_space: true
      plugins: ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "voxel_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /lidar/scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      voxel_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"
        enabled: True
        publish_voxel_map: True
        origin_z: 0.0
        z_resolution: 0.05
        z_voxels: 16
        max_obstacle_height: 2.0
        mark_threshold: 0
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /lidar/scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.55
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  global_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False
  global_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False

map_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    yaml_filename: "map.yaml"

map_saver:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    save_map_timeout: 5.0
    free_thresh_default: 0.25
    occupied_thresh_default: 0.65
    map_subscribe_transient_local: True

planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    expected_planner_frequency: 20.0
    use_sim_time: False
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
    GridBased:
      plugin: "nav2_smac_planner/SmacPlannerLattice"
      tolerance: 0.1                     # tolerance for planning if unable to reach exact pose, in meters
      lattice_filepath: "$(find-pkg-share navigation)/config/lattice_planner.json" 
      downsample_costmap: false           # whether or not to downsample the map
      downsampling_factor: 1              # multiplier for the resolution of the costmap layer (e.g. 2 on a 5cm costmap would be 10cm)
      allow_unknown: false                # allow traveling in unknown space
      max_iterations: 1000000             # maximum total iterations to search for before failing (in case unreachable), set to -1 to disable
      max_on_approach_iterations: 1000    # maximum number of iterations to attempt to reach goal once in tolerance
      max_planning_time: 3.5              # max time in s for planner to plan, smooth, and upsample. Will scale maximum smoothing and upsampling times based on remaining time after planning.
      cost_travel_multiplier: 2.0         # For 2D: Cost multiplier to apply to search to steer away from high cost areas. Larger values will place in the center of aisles more exactly (if non-`FREE` cost potential field exists) but take slightly longer to compute. To optimize for speed, a value of 1.0 is reasonable. A reasonable tradeoff value is 2.0. A value of 0.0 effective disables steering away from obstacles and acts like a naive binary search A*.
      angle_quantization_bins: 64         # For Hybrid nodes: Number of angle bins for search, must be 1 for 2D node (no angle search)
      analytic_expansion_ratio: 3.5       # For Hybrid/Lattice nodes: The ratio to attempt analytic expansions during search for final approach.
      analytic_expansion_max_length: 3.0    # For Hybrid/Lattice nodes: The maximum length of the analytic expansion to be considered valid to prevent unsafe shortcutting (in meters). This should be scaled with minimum turning radius and be no less than 4-5x the minimum radius
      analytic_expansion_max_cost_override: true
      minimum_turning_radius: 0.3       # For Hybrid/Lattice nodes: minimum turning radius in m of path / vehicle
      reverse_penalty: 4.0                # For Reeds-Shepp model: penalty to apply if motion is reversing, must be => 1
      change_penalty: 0.05                 # For Hybrid nodes: penalty to apply if motion is changing directions, must be >= 0
      non_straight_penalty: 1.05          # For Hybrid nodes: penalty to apply if motion is non-straight, must be => 1
      cost_penalty: 2.0                   # For Hybrid nodes: penalty to apply to higher cost areas when adding into the obstacle map dynamic programming distance expansion heuristic. This drives the robot more towards the center of passages. A value between 1.3 - 3.5 is reasonable.
      retrospective_penalty: 0.015        # For Hybrid/Lattice nodes: penalty to prefer later maneuvers before earlier along the path. Saves search time since earlier nodes are not expanded until it is necessary. Must be >= 0.0 and <= 1.0
      rotation_penalty: 0.5              # For Lattice node: Penalty to apply only to pure rotate in place commands when using minimum control sets containing rotate in place primitives. This should always be set sufficiently high to weight against this action unless strictly necessary for obstacle avoidance or there may be frequent discontinuities in the plan where it requests the robot to rotate in place to short-cut an otherwise smooth path for marginal path distance savings.
      lookup_table_size: 20.0               # For Hybrid nodes: Size of the dubin/reeds-sheep distance window to cache, in meters.
      cache_obstacle_heuristic: true      # For Hybrid nodes: Cache the obstacle map dynamic programming distance expansion heuristic between subsiquent replannings of the same goal location. Dramatically speeds up replanning performance (40x) if costmap is largely static.  
      allow_reverse_expansion: false      # For Lattice nodes: Whether to expand state lattice graph in forward primitives or reverse as well, will double the branching factor at each step.   
      smooth_path: true                   # For Lattice/Hybrid nodes: Whether or not to smooth the path, always true for 2D nodes.
      smoother:
        max_iterations: 1000
        w_smooth: 0.3
        w_data: 0.2
        tolerance: 1.0e-10
        do_refinement: true               # Whether to recursively run the smoother 3 times on the results from prior runs to refine the results further

planner_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

recoveries_server:
  ros__parameters:
    costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
    footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
    cycle_frequency: 10.0
    recovery_plugins: ["spin", "backup", "wait"]
    spin:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Spin"
    backup:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/BackUp"
    wait:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Wait"
    global_frame: odom
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    transform_timeout: 0.1
    use_sim_time: true
    simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
    max_rotational_vel: 1.0
    min_rotational_vel: 0.4
    rotational_acc_lim: 3.2

robot_state_publisher:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

waypoint_follower:
  ros__parameters:
    loop_rate: 200
    stop_on_failure: false
    waypoint_task_executor_plugin: "wait_at_waypoint"   
    wait_at_waypoint:
      plugin: "nav2_waypoint_follower::WaitAtWaypoint"
      enabled: True
      waypoint_pause_duration: 200

  
velocity_smoother:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    smoothing_frequency: 20.0
    scale_velocities: False
    feedback: "OPEN_LOOP"
    max_velocity: [0.5, 0.0, 2.0]
    min_velocity: [-0.5, 0.0, -2.0]
    max_accel: [2.5, 0.0, 5.2]
    max_decel: [-2.5, 0.0, -5.2]
    odom_topic: "odom"
    odom_duration: 0.1
    deadband_velocity: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    velocity_timeout: 1.0


You should be able to navigate closer to the walls - it seems more like the controller is rejecting going closer to the wall than it is Smac Planner? If that's the  case, you should focus on the controller's configuration. RPP is more a path follower and you might find it better to use something like MPPI to handle that. But, I think you should probably be able to make RPP work for it too with some tuning.

tolerance: 0.1

If you know the goal is definitely reachable, you can set this to 0.0 so that you only get exact paths that should result in your goal. If you're overly confined, I might suggest moving to the Hybrid-A* planner since it has smaller motion primitives so it can make more fine maneuvers when in confined spots -- given you're using a differential drive robot without the need for explicit minimum control sets like State Lattice provides.

I am able to plan until I am outside this cyan field (I called it obstacle margin). If I am planning a movement closer than that margin then I am getting an error from controller server that the goal has failed. I should mention this before saying about use of Smac Planner. Currently this margin is something about 28 cm and it's too much for our application since we need the robot moving closer to the walls. Is there something more than can be done with controller server to allow me for that?

You may wish to use another controller than RPP, that is not really great for close-to-obstacles navigation since it is a pure path follower and won't try to deviate for intent. I'd recommend MPPI.

Thanks! Will MPPI follow also an exact path provided from for eg. coverage server? That is the reason why I was using RPP since robot should move on the planned path but also close to the walls

It can be tuned to do that, but out of the box it has more flexible behavior
